Facing some errors when running sort with nfq
I installed snort3 on a container using the document provided on snort website, snort installation was successful, then there are other containers running on same network space as of snort, and through one of those containers, I am trying to push icmp(for now) packets to NFQUEUE num 1, and through this NFQUEUE num 1, snort is suppose to get the packets, I followed a document on snort website for the samedocument , now when i am trying to run snort with command(snort -Q --daq nfq --daq-var debug --daq-var device=any --daq-var daq-mode=inline --daq-var queue=1 -c /usr/local/etc/snort/snort.lua), I am getting following error(++ [0]
Error receiving message from the DAQ instance: nfq_daq_msg_receive: Netlink message processing failed: -1 - Operation not permitted (1)
-- [0]
)
And IPTable rules which i added for the same are as follows:
iptables-legacy -t mangle -N SNORT
iptables-legacy -t mangle -I abc 3 -p icmp -j SNORT
iptables-legacy -t mangle -A SNORT -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1
Please help me to find out what the issue is.
Thanks

What version of Ubuntu are you running? https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask Is a good place to start.

I am using  Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-107-generic x86_64)

First your link to the Snort doc is broken please fix that so we can see which doc you're using. I'm no Snort expert but I went through this setup recently in Docker and then lost all my notes so I'm going through it again, the nfq/iptables part.
Theres possibly a good doc out there I remember, I'll try to find it again, I need it!
Also you're not being clear, you say "then there are other containers running on same network space as of snort" is this all in Docker?
Please update your question to clarify that and fix the link and I'll try to help in a day or two.

Here actually look at the startup.sh and the snort.lua here to get some ideas but it's not quite working yet https://github.com/jimlohse/firewallProjectPublic

updated the document link @JimLohse

This error is coming when another application is running on same network which is also using nfqueue but a different queue, i need to find out what resource it is occupying which is restricting snort to execute

Running the container with --privileged will likely fix this, but then you have the security issues related to running a container privileged. I'm trying to figure this out myself, how to accomplish this without running --privileged.
I can't pass judgement on most of your config, I would try to simplify things a bit.
I have a repo with some ideas about what you're trying to do:
https://github.com/jimlohse/firewallProjectPublic

This error is coming when another application is running on same network which is also using nfqueue but a different queue number, i need to find out what resource it is occupying which is restricting snort to execute
